# Larger client-side cache/storage Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, browser, local-storage, blazor-webassembly

We need to store about 50MB of client data in a cache on the client. This data will be read from the client local cache on app start in order to start the app faster. Our app is a ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WebAssembly app. What is the preferred way of doing this? localStorage can only handle 5MB. The data is a big JSON object so also the deserialization and serialization should hopefully be as smooth as possible.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use IndexedDB. Moredetails, you could refer to this article. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

Comment: @Smith5727 Did you figure out how to accomplish this functionality? I am somewhat in same situation and unable to find a feasible solution.

Comment: @OnurBuyukcaglar we ended up using IndexedDB to store this data. As far as we know there is no other convenient way to store a lot of data in Blazor WebAssembly app directly in the browser.